# javascript not included in colorbox popup window

Tags: javascript, colorbox

I am using color box, its really fun, but i am really stucked out by a problem that:

my form is opening in colorbox
i am using jquery for validation in that form
for which i am including validate.js in that page
the problem is that i am not able to see the js file, when i open the page in window it is ok but when that page is opened in colorbox the javascript in not available.
please help me

Answer (score 1):

From the [Colorbox Home Page](http://colorpowered.com/colorbox/):

> #### JavaScript/jQuery is not working inside of ColorBox.
>
> This is often due
> to trying to access an element before
> it has been loaded into the document
> and can be resolved by moving the
> JavaScript into ColorBox's onComplete
> callback.

```
   //Example (using jQuery Forms plugin):
   $('#login_window').colorbox({onComplete:function(){
   $('form#login').ajaxForm();
   }});
```

It looks like you might just need to make use of the "onComplete" callback of the plugin.

Comment: I was going to suggest `$(function(){})` but you can't top the manual! ;)